# Aria on fixed element

Tags: html, css, wai-aria

I'm trying to make an app that renders in a webkit better to use with screen readers. It's mostly working well the only issue is the menu bar that appears at the bottom of the screen is not working correctly. When the app is scrolled to the top it works fine. BUt when it's scrolled down the box that appears around the button when tapped appears above the button. The box moves more the more the page is scrolled and double tapping does not activate it. Is there a way to tell the screen reader the element is in a fixed position?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Screen readers do not rely on CSS. They use the active DOM, which means that the order of HTML elements dictates where the reader goes next. What do you mean by "the box"? Please give a visual representation, such as a link to a simple jsfiddle.

Comment: Sorry projects underwraps so can't show a screenshot. By the box I mean the small box that appears when using TalkBack mode on Android devices. Tapping an element brings it up and double tapping activates it. Except I can only select and the selection box appears in the wrong area

Comment: You can provide a stripped down visual showing only the problem area.